# How to continue combining two fields in form into one field?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access-2010, expressionbuilder

I'm new to this whole microsoft access. I have created a form titled employee and have put it into design view. In a separate table the records of employees information is entered. I have to add the full name of each employee and have done only one. I'm having difficulty in adding another name that is different from the first.

So the expression I used for the first one was =Nz([First], "") & " " & Nz([Last], "")

Answer (score 0):

You should use this expression to avoid the space when *First* is Null:

```
=([First] + " ") & [Last]
```

Then go to a new record and insert *First* and *Last* name.